# How to return value from function that has a Map.prototype.forEach block that makes asynchronous calls?

Tags: typescript, async-await

I've got a block of code that essentially is like this:

```
async getExportData() {
   const exportStats: Object[] = [];
   this.mongoRepositories.forEach( async (repo, key) => {
       await repo.connect();
       let queryResult = await repo.getData();
       exportStats.push(...queryResult);
       repo.close();
    });        
  return exportStats;
}
```

`this.mongoRepositories` is a `Map<string, MongoRepo>`.

How to I return the complete `exportStats` array? The way it's currently written, it's empty at the bottom of the block.

EDIT: This question resulted being different than the potential duplicate due to differences in iterating over a Map and iterating over an Array. Updating question title to reflect.

Comment: have you tried returning a Promise or Observable?

Comment: Check [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: There is another subtle problem with your code - given those requests run independently and asynchronously, is it still fine to `repo.close()` on a global object?

Comment: @zerkms This is a great thing to consider. Fortunately, given this is a lightly used internal tool, the likelihood that there's any issue with closing the connection is minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried iterating it without using `Map.prototype.forEach`, but I couldn't find a way that would compile, even though I found many examples. Turns out I had to update my target to `es6` from `es5` and enable `downlevelIteration` in my `tsconfig.json` file. Then it compiled.

Then I restructured the block as follows:

```
async getExportStats() {
  return await this.queryMongo();
}

private async queryMongo() {
   const exportStats: Object[] = [];
   for (const [key, repo] of this.mongoRepos.entries()) {
     await repo.connect();
     const queryResult = await repo.getExportStats();
     exportStats.push(...queryResult);
 }
   return exportStats;
}
```

This resolved the issue.

Comment: Just a quick comment, `of this.mongoRepos.entries()` is redundant. You can just use `of this.mongoRepos` which is shorthand for `this.mongoRepos[Symbol.iterator]()`, since `Map.prototype[Symbol.iterator] === Map.prototype.entries`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `await` in a `for` loop. If you want to improve throughput, use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to connect concurrently to each repository and query your data. Finally, use [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to spread each of the results into the 1D array of objects that gets returned from collection of query results.

```
async getExportData() {
  const queryResults: Object[][] = await Promise.all(
    Array.from(this.mongoRepositories).map(async ([key, repo]) => {
      await repo.connect();
      const queryResult: Object[] = await repo.getData();
      repo.close();
      return queryResult;
    })
  );
  return queryResults.flat();
}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, I'm unable to call `Array.prototype.flat()` at the end like you did. I get `Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'Object[][]'`.

Comment: Easy workaround though (See link below). Thanks for the efficiency bump. Doing it my way took about 3 seconds, while yours took only about 1.4 seconds. Twice as fast.

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: @Trevor yeah, [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) isn't supported in Node.js until version 11 I believe, along with support for [`Symbol.asyncIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator)